# Searching List<T>

Tags: c#

I have a `List<string>` containing file paths. How can I check if there is a particular file in my list e.g. `file.txt`? Preferably a method returning not a `bool` value but <strike>list</strike> element or element's index.

I've read the `List<T>` documentation but it only confused me as I'm a beginning programmer and my English isn't very good.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Search list of objects based on object variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154310/search-list-of-objects-based-on-object-variable)

Comment: list.Find(item => item.Contains("file.txt"));

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [Where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx) to get a list of values:

```
      var found = fileList.
            Where((f)=>System.IO.Path.GetFileName(f)
                                  .Equals(SEARCH_VALUE, 
                                   StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

or use [FirstOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/bb340482.aspx) for single element or `null` in case it's not found

Comment: possibly its the case sensitivity, I can't read minds though.

Comment: and it clearly states in the question the OP would like a list of matches, or indecies.

Comment: @Jodrell: good point, changed to Where call, so OP gets the list of results.

Comment: Oops, not clearly but even wrong. I've edited my question. Sorry

Answer (score 2):

The [`IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4w08k17.aspx) method is what you need, if you want to find the path that exactly watches what you are looking for.

However, if you what to find paths in your list that end with a certain file name, you can do,

```
var matches = paths.Select((path, i) => new { Path = path, Index = i })
    .Where(item => Path.GetFileName(item.Path).Equals(
        "file.txt",
        StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

However, note that `matches` will be a sequence of 0 or more matches. So, you can do,

```
if (matches.Any())
{
    // I found something.
    foreach (var match in matches)
    {
       var matchIndex = match.Index;
       var matchPath = match.Path;
    }
}
else
{
    // Oops, no matches.
}
```

or, if you only want the first.

```
var firstMatchPath = matches.First().Path;
```

would do.

Comment: Wrong. This will find "myfile.txt", too!

Answer (score 2):

If your list contains the full path (like c:\windows\system.ini") I would use `System.IO.Path.GetFileName` and also keep in mind to search case intenstive

```
var result = from f in files
             where Path.GetFileName(f).Equals("file.txt",
                   StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
             select f;

bool found = result.Any();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use LINQ (assuming you havethe paths as strings):

```
var found = from f in fileList where f.equals("file.txt") select f;
```

Comment: This one won't find "File.txt", also you mixed f and n

Comment: @SchlaWiener cause of the mixed n and f or for some other reason?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the first value if there is one then you can do this.

```
var value = mylist.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.EndsWith("file.txt"));
```

or if you want to do something with each matching string.

```
foreach (string value in mylist.Where(x=>x.EndsWith("file.txt")) )
{
    // Do whatever you intend with value.
}
```

or if you want a list of the indices of the values, then you could try this.

```
var indexValues = new List<int>();
foreach (string value in mylist.Where(x=>x.EndsWith("file.txt")) )
{
    indexValues.Add(mylist.IndexOf(value));
}
```

Comment: This will crash if it's not there?

Comment: It won't compile because of the missing ).

Comment: Wrong, will find "myfile.txt", too.

Comment: Oops, could have sworn the question was if string has the filename in it. Thanks, changed to suit question.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question, but it seems that the list will contain file paths, but what you are looking for is a filename.

The following code will give you the index of the first occurrence of a file called "file.txt" in the list of path names, or -1 if it isn't in the list.

Note how this uses `Path.GetFileName()`. This is so that it will match "c:\dir1\dir2\file.txt" and not "c:\dir1\dir2\wrongfile.txt".

```
int index = filenames.FindIndex(filename => Path.GetFileName(filename).Equals("file.txt", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

However, if you are searching for an entire path then you can do it like this:

```
int index = filenames.FindIndex(filename => filename.Equals("file.txt", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

Note how we do a comparison of the entire filename rather than using "EndsWith".

If the filenames are already all lowercase and you are comparing entire paths then you can do a simpler search:

```
int index = filenames.IndexOf("file.txt");
```

Or if they are all uppercase you'd have to do:

```
int index = filenames.IndexOf("FILE.TXT");
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you have path and file name is located at the end of path:

```
        //List of elements
        List<string> foundElements = myInitialList.Where(s => s.EndsWith("file.txt")).ToList();

        //List of Indexes (base on lift of elements here above)
        List<int> indexList = new List<int>();
        foundElements.ForEach(f => indexList.Add(myInitialList.IndexOf(f)));
```